# Movie about a spaceship capable of absorbing other spaceships

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely remember a movie about a rocket ship that could open its hull front to absorb other rockets. The tip of the rocket was a mechanised cone split into 4 separate door shutters, similarly to the face of the Demogorgon from *Stranger Things* or the sand worm from *Dune*. It was flying about in space and swallowing other ships and stripping / rebuilding them (?).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?  Live action or animated?

Comment: It's not [*You Only Live Twice*](https://i.redd.it/38mnw1g0sy151.jpg) is it?

Comment: Absorbing is an interesting word choice, implying an almost biological process. Was there anything about the spaceship that seemed non-technological?

Answer (score 21):

That's the James Bond film [You Only Live Twice.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Only_Live_Twice_(film))

Comment: This was my first thought from the description

Comment: Also note that everything in this film is well within Elon Musk's capabilities.

Comment: @Valorum So he could start cleaning up orbital debris any day?  Yeah, okay, only if there was a profit in it...

Comment: @ZeissIkon There might be...the odd bit of actual space junk might get big bids on Ebay, particularly if you could ID it as historically significant.  Probably would have to warehouse and ration them to keep the price high, like diamonds.  A smaller spacecraft would probably be more efficient, since you'd be changing orbits a lot.

Comment: @ZeissIkon The real problem is finding debris the size and shape of a space capsule.

Comment: @Valorum Well, within the capabilities of the companies he buys

Comment: Rocket Lab's Neutron rocket might be adapted for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lab_Neutron

Comment: @Valorum Only if he also owns a white cat...

Comment: I don't recall the spaceship "stripping / rebuilding" the captured ship.  (It's been a long time since I watched the movies, though.)

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is the alien spaceship in the *Lost in Space* episode "The Derelict" September22, 1965, which opened up a sort of nose cone and swallowed the Jupiter Two.   The alien ship was definately not a rocketship, though.

*You only live Twice* (1967) might have been partially inspired by the "angry alligator" of Gemini IX in may, 1966.

*https://www.nasa.gov/feature/gemini-ix-crew-found-angry-alligator-in-earth-orbit*

Of course the spacecraft in "The Derelict" and *You only live Twice* (1967) didn't disassemble or rebuild the spaceships they swallowed, so possibly the op remembers some other movie or tv show.